# How to efficiently map entries in a dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, optimization, pandas

I've been a fan of stackoverflow for a long time and I've found it very useful. However, this time I felt the need for asking a performance related question about code I've written, and I hope I can get some valuabe help from the community.

My question pertains to a problem of recommending ads to a given user in the "users" dataframe (see below), where each ad in the "adids" dataframe must fulfill certain criteria in order to be recommended to a user. The data is on the form:

```
users = pd.DataFrame({"loginid" : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], 
                  "min_price" : [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 10], 
                  "max_price" : [30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30], 
                  "municipal" : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e"] })
```

and the ads dataframe looks like this:

```
adids = pd.DataFrame({"adid" : [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105], 
                  "totalprice" : [11., 15, 15, 25, 35, 25], 
                  "municipal" : ["a", "a", "d", "d", "e", "d"]})
```

What I want to achieve (efficiently) is a filtering of relevant ads for a given user (i.e. a given loginid). Currently, I'm populating a dictionary called "adsdict", where the keys are a user's loginid, and the values are all the recommended adids. An ad is recommended, if "totalprice" is between a user's max and min price range (given by "min_price" and "max_price") and the user has a match on municipality as well. The code below achieves this, however, I am uncertain about how efficiently I am doing this. On my full dataset, which is very large (order of 10^6++ rows) this part is definitely my bottleneck when it comes to time consumption.

```
adsdict = {}

unique_logins = np.unique(users.loginid)
for logid in unique_logins:
    row_indexer = (users.loginid == logid)
    user = users[row_indexer]
    max_price = user.ix[row_indexer, "max_price"].max()
    min_price = user.ix[row_indexer, "min_price"].min()
    row_indexer_2 = (adids.totalprice >= min_price) \
                                & (adids.totalprice <= max_price)    
    ads = adids.loc[row_indexer_2, ["adid", "municipal"]]
    adsdict[logid] = list( pd.merge(user, ads, on="municipal").adid.values )
```

On my toy data set, the output becomes:

```
0: [100, 101], 1: [103, 105, 104]}
```

which is the desired result. However, as specified earlier, I fear that they way I am coding this is inefficient, since I have to perform a join-operation for each loginid.

I would greatly appreciate it, if more experienced python users (I am using python 3.4, with pandas 0.16.2) could give advice on how to optimize this. I am open to all sorts of (fast!) solutions, but memory is also a factor (although I have access to a server with a lot of memory, so this is not the most critical issue at the moment.) So, the solution need not even use a dictionary, the only criterion I have, is to be able to see which ads that have been recommended to a given user (loginid).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Magnus

Ps. I have tried to conform to best practices when it comes to posting a queston on here. My apologies in advance, if I have neglected to provide necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so first of all you need to find the `users` with matched `municipal` from `ads` , you can do this simply by merging the two frames , this is how you fulfill your first condition

```
In [15]:
match_minicipal_df = pd.merge(users , adids , on = 'municipal')
match_minicipal_df
Out[15]:
loginid    max_price    min_price   municipal   adid    totalprice
0               30          10          a       100         11
0               30          10          a       101         15
1               40          20          d       102         15
1               40          20          d       103         25
1               40          20          d       105         25
1               40          20          e       104         35
0               30          10          e       104         35
```

then in order to fulfill your second condition which is the `total` should be between the `min` and `max` values you can do this by

```
In [32]:
match = np.logical_and(match_minicipal_df.totalprice > match_minicipal_df.min_price , match_minicipal_df.totalprice < match_minicipal_df.max_price)
match
Out[32]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

the last step to slice your `dataframe` based on your conditions

```
In [33]:
match_minicipal_df[match]
Out[33]:
loginid max_price     min_price municipal   adid    totalprice
0           30              10      a       100         11
0           30              10      a       101         15
1           40              20      d       103         25
1           40              20      d       105         25
1           40              20      e       104         35
```

as you can see here

```
In [53]:
match_minicipal_df.ix[match ,['loginid' , 'adid'] ]
Out[53]:
loginid adid
0       100
0       101
1       103
1       105
1       104
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nader, much appreciated. Very fast answer as well.